# Hide specific columns from pivot key

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

I have 2 tables say `abc` and `xyz` with `ManyToMany` relationship built over another table say `abc_xyz` (whose data will be returned as `pivot` key). However, `pivot` key upon retrieval has `abc_id` and `xyz_id` in return. I am able to access other columns in from `abc_xyz` table using method `withPivot('dummy')`

But, I want to hide the `abc_id` and `xyz_id` from the response. How do I do that? 
I can hide the entire `pivot` key by using $hidden array but I want to hide only specific columns not the entire key.

*Current Response*

```
{
   "abc_uuid": "some uuid",
   "xyz" : [
       {
           "xyz_uuid": "some uuid",
           "pivot": {
                "abc_id": 1,
                "xyz_id": 1,
                "dummy" : "dummy value"
            }
       },
       {
           "xyz_uuid": "some uuid",
           "pivot": {
                "abc_id": 1,
                "xyz_id": 2,
                "dummy" : "dummy value"
            }
       }
   ]
}
```

So, I need only `dummy` from the `pivot` key, and hide `abc_id` and `xyz_id`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a crude way to get this done. Found this answer in laravel issues unable to find the link now. However, it asks me to just add a method in my model and unset the keys I do not want.

```
public function toArray()
{
    $attributes = $this->attributesToArray();
    $attributes = array_merge($attributes, $this->relationsToArray());
    foreach($attributes['xyz'] as $key => $value) {
        unset($value['pivot']['abc_id']);
        unset($value['pivot']['xyz_id']);
        $attributes['xyz'][$key] = $value;
    }
    return $attributes;
}
```

this unsets the unwanted keys from my response. I hope laravel gives out an easy way for this.

Comment: Why is this down voted? Any better solution? I would at least like to see a reason for the downvote

Comment: from the question to the awnser, what model should I add this?

Comment: @francisco you should add it in question.